# Check if a Python string is a valid Excel cell

Tags: python, excel, string, openpyxl

Given some alphanumerical strings in Python such as

- `A9`
- `B44B`
- `C101`
- `4D4`

how do I check if the string is a valid Excel cell (i.e., **letters come before numbers**)?

I've tried using the `.isalpha` and `.isdigit` methods to "gather" letters and numbers, and then using `.index` to check whether all letters appear before numbers, but my logic is becoming too complex, and I feel like I'm not accounting for all possibilities.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Expected result:

```
>>> is_valid_excel_cell('A9')
True
>>> is_valid_excel_cell('B44B')
False
>>> is_valid_excel_cell('C101')
True
>>> is_valid_excel_cell('4D4')
False
```

Comment: ***Note:*** Something to keep in mind, validity can depend on excel version. E.g.: Excel2003 only has 256 columns and 65536 rows where newer versions have 16384 columns and 1048676 rows.

Comment: regex is probably the best bet: `re.match("[A-Z]+\d+$",cellcontent)`

Comment: Would it be fair to say you only care about detecting when a letter comes directly after a number?

Comment: @JvdV you're right, although this souldn't be an issue for my use case. I did not explain this but I don't mean to write the Excel file back to memory, just read its values (`openpyxl` allows accessing cells beyond Excel's limit, although they all store `None` values).

Comment: @pipinstallMonica mostly yes although I'd like to check if it's an actual Excell cell (i.e. `'1'` and `'A'` should return `False` since those are Excel columns/rows, not cells).

Comment: openpyxl actually provides the necessary functions in the `utils` module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my comment, validity depends on Excel version. Newer versions have a column range of `A-XDF` and rows from `1-1048576`. It might not be necessary in your project, but for future reference it could be handy:

Regex pattern: `^([A-Z]{1,2}|[A-W][A-Z]{2}|X[A-E][A-Z]|XF[A-D])([1-9]\d{0,6})$`

To visualize this:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

First group captures the column reference for Excel 2010 and higher which is `A-XDF`, and the second group captures the numeric part which should always start with `1-9` followed by 0 to 6 characters but cannot exceed `1048576`.

So in full effect you could think about:

```
import re
def is_valid_excel_cell(c):
    m = re.match(r'^([A-Z]{1,2}|[A-W][A-Z]{2}|X[A-E][A-Z]|XF[A-D])([1-9]\d{0,6})$',c)
    return bool(m) and int(m.group(2)) < 1048577
```

Comment: While I don't need this functionality as of right now, I agree that this is the more generalist answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would use regular expressions, well fit for the task:

```
import re

def is_valid_excel_cell(c):
    m = re.match("[A-Z]+\d+$",c)
    return bool(m)
```

that one checks if the cell contents starts with a capital letter and ends with a digit.

Now if range check is required on the number one more step would be required, one can extract the digits and convert them to integer, compare to a range (I'll let the reader adjust the range, as I'm not a excel expert).

```
def is_valid_excel_cell(c):
    m = re.match("[A-Z]+(\d+)$",c)
    return bool(m) and m.group(1).isdigit() and 0 < int(m.group(1)) < 16384
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly as intended. And of course the answer would involve regex... :)

Comment: I've added some more extensive regex pattern to your great answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def is_valid_excel_cell(addr):
    m = re.match(r'^([A-Z]{1,3})([1-9]\d*)$', addr)
    if not m:
        return False
    letters, numbers = m.groups()
    if len(letters) == 3 and letters > 'XFD':
        return False
    if int(numbers) > 1048576:
        return False
    return True
```

Semicompressed for Python 3.8+ only (due to the use of the walrus (`:=`) operator):

```
def is_valid_excel_cell(addr):
    return (bool(m := re.match(r'^([A-Z]{1,3})([1-9]\d*)$', addr)) and
        (len(m.group(1)) < 3 or m.group(1) <= 'XFD') and 
        int(m.group(2)) <= 1048576)
```

Comment: Very clever usage of checking letters against XFD there, +. Looks like a combination of answers is just what OP could use: `m = re.match(r'^([A-Z]{1,3})([1-9]\d{0,6})$',c)` >> `return bool(m) and m.group(1) < 'XFE' and int(m.group(2)) < 1048577`

Comment: @JvdV: `'ZZ' < 'XFE'` is false so that should only be checked when group 1 has a length of 3.  Once I saw it in your answer I very much liked the idea of shortening it up, but ultimately I decided to leave it as is to make the logic apparent to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

When using openpyxl one can call [coordinate_from_string](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.coordinate_from_string) method to check if it properly returns column and row.

```
def validate_cell(value=None, default=None):
    if not value:
        return default

    # validate provided string
    try:
        from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string
        column, row = coordinate_from_string(str(value).upper())
    except:
        return default

    # validate values
    if not column or not row:
        return default

    return '%s%i' % (column, row)
```